# .htaccess file not removing file extension online

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the .html extension from my file name. This was working locally for me but stopped working, Online it did not work at all. The code I am using to remove the .html file extension is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC]


AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Anyone have any other solution?

Comment: quick tip: make sure you have rights to use a mod rewrite on your server

Comment: im actually using my cousins server. Do i have to get himt o enable this?

Comment: If you want to use mod rewrite on Apache you do need the privilege for it, yes...